# Dual Space, Vector

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $x,y$ which are in $V^{\ast}$ ( dual space)

Suppose that $\ker(x)\subset \ker(y)$.

Prove that there is a scalar $C$ such that

$x=Cy$

Do you have any ideas?

full explanation please  because  i am very new to the term of dual space

Comment: Is there a chance you forgot to add the condition that the dimension of $\;V^*\;$ is finite?

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false: if $y=0$, then its kernel is $V$, so $\ker x\subset\ker y$, for all $x$, but obviously there is no $C$ when $x\ne0$.

The correct statement is that there exists $C$ such that $y=Cx$.

If $y=0$, just take $C=0$.

Suppose $y\ne0$ (so also $x\ne0$). Then $\ker x$ is a maximal subspace of $V$, because $V/\ker x$ is a one dimensional vector space. The same is true for $\ker y$; therefore $\ker x=\ker y$.

Let $u\in V$ such that $x(u)\ne0$; then also $y(u)\ne0$. Set $C=y(u)/x(u)$.

If $v\in V$, then $v=\alpha u+w$ for some scalar $\alpha$ and some $w\in\ker x=\ker y$. Then $x(v)=\alpha x(u)$ and $y(v)=\alpha y(u)$, so
$$
Cx(v)=\frac{y(u)}{x(u)}\alpha x(u)=\alpha y(u)=y(v)
$$